Convert SF points and multilinestring to adjacency matrix
I've got a set of points (in long and lat), and a single multilinestring. Is it possible to get an adjacency matrix, of distances ALONG this line?
Edit: There are 13 sensor locations, all of which lie along various branches, which has been combined in to a single multilinestring, which can be thought of as a network/graph. I'm wishing to compute the shortest path distance between each of the sensors.
Similar to this answer here, but the points are given, instead of generated: Combine Multilinestring into one line string to generate regular spaced points using sf
reprex below:
library(sf)
library(SSNdata)
library(osmdata)
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

## Import data.frame containing observations and covariates
clear <- readRDS(system.file("extdata/clear_obs.RDS", package = "SSNdata"))

# Get the river lines
lines <- (opq(bbox = clear$river %>%
                gsub(pattern = "_", replacement = " ") %>%
                unique %>%
                str_to_title,
              timeout = 2000,
              memsize = 10e8) %>%
            add_osm_feature(key = 'waterway', value = c('river', 'stream')) %>%
            osmdata_sf())$osm_lines


sensors <- structure(
  list(
    section = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                11, 12), 
    geometry = structure(
      list(structure(c(169.893668510998, -43.4485707831223), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.905356945663, -43.4501164165107), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.9072738056,-43.4465855404346), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.9019276, -43.4494298), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.88333135407, -43.451279558067), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.883056036222,-43.4554894608215), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.898097916634, -43.4588427716324), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.88278569869, -43.4602902410717), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.924591882517, -43.4496436972259), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.919694386786, -43.4442892230613), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.8837607, -43.4711193), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.918834656941, -43.4659988545691), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), 
           structure(c(169.902468538258, -43.4638261136778), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), 
      n_empty = 0L, 
      crs = structure(
        list(input = "WGS 84", 
             wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), 
        class = "crs"), 
      class = c("sfc_POINT","sfc"), 
      precision = 0, 
      bbox = structure(c(xmin = 169.88278569869,ymin = -43.4711193, xmax = 169.924591882517, ymax = -43.4442892230613), class = "bbox"))), 
  row.names = c(NA, -13L), 
  class = c("sf","data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", 
  agr = structure(c(FID = NA_integer_), class = "factor", 
                  levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity")))


# Convert to a  multilinestring
concat <- lines %>% 
  st_touches() %>% 
  graph_from_adj_list() %>% 
  components() %>% 
  pluck(membership)

concat_lines <- group_by(
  lines,
  section = as.character({{concat}})
  ) %>% 
  summarise()

# Get the main multilinestring of interest
main_line <- concat_lines[2,]

line <- main_line %>% st_as_sfc
point <- sensors %>% st_as_sfc

distances <- sf::st_line_project(line, point)

from the dev version of sf on GitHub has this solution, but it doesn't work on my use case (keeps giving, Error: Incompatible lengths: 141, 13)

Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve for the sake of us non-hydrologists? For instance, a quick glance at your data shows the sensors are on seven(?) different branches (six if you combine two of the top three). So when you say "distances along this line", how are you defining the origin to measure the distance from? Do you want the distance to be measured from a single origin for all sensors? Or distance along each individual branch?

Hi @LTyrone I'll pop some extra information in the Q

Figured it out!
Need to first convert the multilinestring to a graph using sfnetworks package, and then can use the igraph::distances function. See below:
library(sfnetworks)

network <-
  main_line %>%
  st_zm(geom) %>%
  st_geometry() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  # back to sfc
  st_sfc(crs = st_crs(main_line)) %>%
  # directed graph
  as_sfnetwork(length_as_weight = TRUE,
               directed = TRUE) %>% 
  # Add sensors as nodes
  st_network_blend(sensors)

length(V(network))

distances <- distances(network,
                       v = 121:133,
                       to = 121:133,
                       mode = "out")

